# tikz and atbegshi

Tags: tikz-pgf

1. The following doesn't show watermark on page 1. How can I get watermark on page 1?
2. `\\` has no effect. How can I force line break?

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{lipsum}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{atbegshi}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \AtBeginShipoutInit
   \AtBeginShipout{%
     \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{%
       \path[use as bounding box](0,0);
       \node [gray!55,inner sep=0pt,rotate=45] at
         ([shift={(.5\paperwidth,-.5\paperheight)}]current page.north west){%
         \scalebox{3}{%
           \fontseries{b}\fontfamily{bch}\fontsize{14.4}{17}\selectfont
           DRAFT\\Page~\thepage
         }%
       };
     }%
   }

   \begin{document}
   \title{Test document}
   \author{Ahmed Musa}
   \maketitle
   \lipsum[1-20]
   \end{document}
   ```

Thanks to Gonzalo Medina for formatting the code.

Comment: There is also the [`draftwatermark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/draftwatermark) package that provides macros to add a simple text watermark.

Comment: You might also be thinking of the `\shortstack` command for forcing a linebreak.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Paul Gaborit found a solution based on [my first attempt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/73944/6) that uses `\AtBeginShipout` *and* `\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox`.

- `\AtBeginShipout` is used to add code before each "shipout" operation.
- `\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox` is used to put material (here `\draftpage`) in the background of the current `\AtBeginShipoutBox`.

With this method, the result always contains *four* pages (with or without draft mark). (The usage of `\AtBeginShipoutFirst`—can be used to add code before the first page—results in more vertical space so that the last line of page 4 ended up on a fifth page.)

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\AtBeginShipoutInit
\newcommand*{\draftpage}{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{%
    \node [text=gray!55,inner sep=0pt,rotate=45,align=center,
    font=\fontseries{b}\fontfamily{bch}\fontsize{43.2}{51}\selectfont]
    at (current page) {DRAFT\\Page~\thepage};
  }%
}

\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{\draftpage}}

\title{Test document}
\author{Ahmed Musa}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-20]
\thepage
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image: correct code]

The second part of the question (which I did oversee when I first answered it) is incorporated and uses percusse's approach using `TikZ`'s `scale` and `align` key.

Comment: @AhmedMusa I've updated my answer. There is still both macros  `\AtBeginShipout` and `\AtBeginShipoutFirst` but I hope the duplication is at its lowest.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel The `page` counter is incremented *after* the page has been shipped out. The *other* counters are incremented just before usage.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for clarification. "_after_" was initially in the first version of my answer but I got confused while I tried to clarify that fact for myself. I hope that the revised version is now correct.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel You can use `\AtBeginShipoutFirst` to add code *before* the first page. The added vertical space  is a switch between vertical and horizontal mode: `\tikz` (or a `tikzpicture`) calls `\leavevmode` even with `overlay` and `remember picture` options!

Comment: @AhmedMusa I don't understand your comment about duplication.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Take a look at the [old versions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/73944/6) of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have found an alternative to using *atbegshi*. I hacked into the output routine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\def\AfterManifest{\g@addto@macro\@aftermanifest}
\def\@aftermanifest{}
\g@addto@macro\document{%
  \let\AfterManifest\@iden
  \@aftermanifest
  \let\AfterManifest\@notprerr
  \global\let\@aftermanifest\relax
  \ignorespaces
}
\AfterManifest{%
  \let\@savedoutputpage\@outputpage
  \def\@outputpage{%
    \let\@savedbegindvi\@begindvi
    \def\@begindvi{%
      \am@watermark
      \@savedbegindvi
    }%
    \@savedoutputpage
    \let\@begindvi\@savedbegindvi
  }%
}
\def\am@watermark{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{%
    \node [text=gray!55,inner sep=0pt,rotate=45,align=center,scale=5,
    font=\fontseries{b}\fontfamily{bch}\selectfont]
    at (current page) {DRAFT\\[1ex]Page~\thepage};
  }%
}
\makeatother

\title{Test document}
\author{Ahmed Musa}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-20]
\thepage
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You must use an older version of MikTeX: the current version of `atbegshi` is 2011/10/05 v1.16!

Comment: What advantages with your method?