# Getting Atbegshi to start on first page and reset content when overwritten

Tags: eso-pic, everyshi

I'm trying to add titles at a specific location (over a letterhead) for a number of pages (1-2) and then add a new title to the following 2. I have two problems. First `AtBegShi` starts at the second page `\AtBeginShipoutFirst` doesn't fix this, and secondly `\AtBeginShipoutDiscard` doesnt reset `AtBegShi` so it has Rhubarb and Custard superimposed.

Any thoughts on this would be extremely gratefully received. thanks

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{textpos}
\AtBeginShipoutInit

\def\mycontent{rhubarb}

\AtBeginShipout{
    \begin{textblock}{6}[0,0](0.1,-0.15)
    \mycontent
    \end{textblock}
    }
    \AtBeginShipoutFirst{
    \begin{textblock}{6}[0,0](0.1,-0.15)
    \mycontent
    \end{textblock}
    }

\begin{document}

blah
\newpage
blah
\newpage
\def\mycontent{custard}

blah
\newpage
blah
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's more convenient to replace `Rhubarb`/`Custard` with a macro, say `\sometext`, and then redefine `\sometext` appropriately.

Comment: Try *xwatermark* package.

Comment: thanks @Werner, that is extremely elegant! Would you happen to know how to get the `shipout` to start from page 1?

Comment: thanks @AhmedMusa. Looking at the documentation for `xwatermark` now. Looks very powerful, but struggling to get to grips with the fontseries options. It hangs if I put `\textbf\textsc{mytext}` in the `{}` braces, and hangs if I use the `fontseries=\bfseries\scshape` formulation. I'm trying to find the series spec for the `\FancyPageNos` macro but a google search hasn't had results. Do you know where the documentation might be available?

Comment: Please can you give a minimal non-working example?

Comment: Hi @AhmedMusa. MWE changed to MNWE. I've adopted Werner's recommendation for changing the reference for `AtBegShi` which works extremely well. Now I just need to figure out how to get it to show up on the first page too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you need *textpos* for, but I was able to generate the following. The watermark appears on pages 1 and 3. You can adjust the key values of `\newwatermark` and `\xwmcolorbox` to suit your need.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\mycontent{rhubarb}
\newwatermark[coord-unit=cm,pagex={1,3},xpos=0,ypos=4]{%
  \xwmcolorbox[framesep=4pt,innerframerule=4pt,outerframerule=2pt,
    fillcolor=brown!70!yellow!55,innerframecolor=white,
    outerframecolor=blue,height=1cm,width=.8\paperwidth,
    depth=.4cm,textalign=center,textcolor=blue]{%
      \scalebox{2.5}{\textbf{\mycontent}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\newpage
\lipsum[1-5]
\newpage
\def\mycontent{custard}
\lipsum[1-5]
\newpage
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @AhmedMusa, that works and I've marked it as answered for all your help. I would still like to now how to get a shipout payload on the first page using `AtBegShi`. Perhaps I'll put it in a separate question.

Comment: See the answers at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73938/tikz-and-atbegshi.