# Extra page when using tikzpicture called by AtBeginShipout?

Tags: tikz-pgf, atbegshi

I have been attempting to use `\AtBeginShipout` and `tikz` to  draw header and footer art as suggested in [solution for creating newsletter art](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121568/99584) by user [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina).

One problem that has been encounter is that an extra page containing only the artwork is always produced at the end of the document.  In the example below I expect two pages of output, but there are three.  Why is this?  What is the best way to prevent it?

Example using `\AtBeginShipout` with `\tikzpicture` produces an extra page:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\DrawSquare{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\draw[fill=pink]
    (0,0) rectangle (10,-10);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\AtBeginShipout{\DrawSquare}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-9]
\end{document}
```

Thumbnail of Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: This question is very similar to: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73938/99584

Comment: I prefere to use the everypage package for headers and footers.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276358/text-on-background-image-footer-and-header/276453?s=8|0.0651#276453 for example.

Comment: @ John-Kormylo,  Thank you for bringing up the everpage package and that question.  I will look into the discussion there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use

```
\AtBeginShipout{<stuff>}
```

`<stuff>` is inserted into the input stream. However, at that point, the entire "current page" has already been constructed and is contained inside the box `\AtBeginShipoutBox`. If you leave everything as-is, the "current page" is shipped out, after which `<stuff>` is processed.

In your instance, an `overlay` box is added to the input stream but doesn't form part of the "current page" to be shipped out.

In order to *add to* the "current page" that will be shipped out, you need to use the combination

```
\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{<stuff>}}
```

or

```
\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{<stuff>}}
```

Comment: Can you provide any insight on why \AtBeginShipoutAddToBox, or something similar, is not also required for \AtBeginShipoutFirst{<stuff>} in order to get stuff  added to the first page?

Comment: @BrianKubera: From the [`atbegshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/atbegshi.pdf): "`AtBeginShipoutFirst{<code>}` ... The `<code>` is directly executed in a `\vbox` that is put at the beginning of the output page. Dealing with the output box `\AtBeginShipoutBox` is not necessary and not permitted here."

Comment: Thank you, I could not make sense of what was going on without your explanation.

Comment: This solution is "partially" working since now the extra pages are gone but i am missing my header and footer data on even numbered pages (I am making even pages blank by using \cleardoublepage or \cleartorecto). I am using memoir class. Can somebody please help.

Comment: @SatyendraRana: How about posting a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) showing your problem? You could also consider posting a [follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764), pointing back to this one as reference.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing:

```
\AtBeginShipout{\DrawSquare}
```

With:

```
\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{\DrawSquare}}
```

Solves the problem.  The output consists of two pages of text, both pages contain a pink square.  However, I can't explain why the problem occurs or why this solution works.

This solution was found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73944/99584).

Comment: If "this solution was found [elsewhere]", could this question be considered a duplicate?

Comment: Yes, I noted the similarity in a comment to the question.  However, the why is not explained here or in the other question.

Comment: @BrianKubera You may read the [documentation of `atbegshi` package](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/oberdiek/atbegshi.pdf#page=3) (p.3).

Comment: I am failing to understand the difference in behavior of \AtBeginShipout and \AtBeginShipoutFirst.  The documentation describes them as both "a hook that executes for"  appropriate page(s).  If I use  \AtBeginShipoutFirst{\DrawSquare} in TeX from the question , the first page will be drawn on, as I would expect.  The same is not true of \AtBeginShipout{\DrawSquare}, the drawing won't be applied until the next page, skipping the first page and creating an additional page.  This is not the behavior I expect from the documentation and seems inconsistent with the behavior of \AtBeginShipoutFirst.