Adding Tikz banner in header and footer adds an extra page to end of document
I am trying to add header and footer banners to my document. But when I try to use Tikz to create the banners, they add an unnecessary extra page at the end of my document. How can I fix this? Here is what I have so far:
\documentclass{article}

% Set page size and margins
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}

% Useful packages
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{atbegshi}  % for inserting images at the start of each page

\definecolor{left}{HTML}{036C9F}
\definecolor{right}{HTML}{31C9FC}

% Header and footer TikZ drawings
\AtBeginShipout{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        % Header gradient
        \node[shading=axis, rectangle, left color=left, right color=right, shading angle=90, 
              anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=40pt] 
              at (current page.north) {};
        
        % Footer gradient
        \node[shading=axis, rectangle, left color=left, right color=right, shading angle=90, 
              anchor=south, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=40pt] 
              at (current page.south) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

% Title and author information
\title{Header Test}
\author{Witt}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\newpage

\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}


I know this is what is causing the extra page because when I remove this section from my .tex file, it removes the extra page at the end.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess, what you are doing ...

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Might be related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296662/extra-page-when-using-tikzpicture-called-by-atbeginshipout although your code does not load the atbegshi package - on the other hand, your code does not compile...

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz fixed the code snippet. It should compile now.
